# Android System Properties

Tags: android

Do the following access the same internal set of properties or is there any difference in their semantics?

- [`java.lang.System.setProperty(String key, String value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`android.os.SystemProperties.set(String key, String value)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/SystemProperties.java#SystemProperties)
- `adb shell setprop 'key' 'value'`

For example, after calling:

```
System.setProperty("myprop", "1");
```

`adb shell getprop myprop` returns an empty string.

---

Note: `SystemProperties` is an internal class, not exposed in the SDK, but used by other system classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SystemProperties.set()` and `adb shell setprop` are inter-operable: they both alter the same system property value.

However, `System.setProperty()` is Java and VM specific, and uses different key/value naming convention.

Comment: I see, what would be the equivalent of 'adb shell setprop myprop 1' using System.setProperty() then? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no such equation between those two. I'd use `SystemProperties` instead.